# Can't reboot after installing 10.04LTS

Tags: boot, partitioning, 10.04, raid

I am trying to upgrade from 8.04LTS to 10.04LTS and onwards to 14.04. I first tried to download 10.04 via the Internet but the install crapped out half way through. I have now tried three times to install 10.04 from a Live USB stick and the installation completes perfectly well but upon restart when I remove the usb stick the machine will not reboot. 10.04 runs fine in "try" mode but simply will not reboot. I think I unwittingly installed two instances of 10.04 so perhaps that explains why it won't reboot?

My environment is an older dual Opteron processor on a  Tyan S2882G3NR-D motherboard with an Adaptec Raid controller with I think 3 hard drives. The machine was always a single boot Ubuntu 8.04 distro and worked well until I tried the online download package upgrade. Under 8.04 the machine first booted the RAID Controller and then it loaded Grub to boot Linux. With the 10.04 installed the RAID boots fine but then hangs when trying to load/boot 10.04. I just get a blank screen with a flashing white cursor and it hangs until I ctrl-alt-del to force the reboot.

Would anyone have any solutions for this problem please? Here is my `fdisk` output:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ `sudo fdisk -l`

Disk /dev/sda: 319.8 GB, 319813582848 bytes 255 heads, 63
sectors/track, 38881 cylinders Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 =
8225280 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes Disk identifier:
0x000027a7

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *           1       38131   306278400   83  Linux
/dev/sda2           38131       38882     6036481    5  Extended
/dev/sda5           38131       38882     6036480   82  Linux swap /
Solaris

Disk /dev/sdb: 160.0 GB, 160041885696 bytes 255 heads, 63
sectors/track, 19457 cylinders Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 =
8225280 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes Disk identifier:
0x00070923

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1               1       19197   154191872   83  Linux
/dev/sdb2           19197       19458     2096129    5  Extended
/dev/sdb5           19197       19458     2096128   82  Linux swap /
Solaris

Disk /dev/sdc: 31.1 GB, 31113347072 bytes 96 heads, 32 sectors/track,
19781 cylinders Units = cylinders of 3072 * 512 = 1572864 bytes Sector
size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes I/O size
(minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes Disk identifier: 0xc3072e18

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdc1   *           3       19782    30380096    c  W95 FAT32
(LBA) ubuntu@ubuntu:~$
```

Comment: Thanks. There is nothing that I need to backup so I could do a fresh install: But that is what I thought I was doing :-( What would or should I do for a fresh install other than what I have done?

Answer (score 1):

Okay in comments you said you want a fresh install and there is nothing to backup. Basically you just want to download 14.04 and burn to disk or put img on usb (if have access to Windows you can use Linux Live USB Creator).

During install process I'm pretty sure one of the options is to wipe everything and do a clean install. Not sure what effect that will have with your raid setup. Might need to reset that up.

If you don't get that option, you may need to back out of install, go to try Ubuntu and use gparted to delete partitions/recreate them.

Comment: Thanks. Before wiping I will have to do some research on how this would affect my RAID.

Comment: Yes. Sorry I can't help with that, but I'm sure it will need something done to get working

Comment: Maybe [This](http://www.ubuntulinuxguide.com/software-raid-ubuntu-14-04-setup-install-configure/) will help

Comment: geoffmcc: That's exactly what I would have said!  ;-)  @RichardLamothe: If it's a hardware RAID, that will have no consequences, if it's a software RAID, just recreate it and start making [system backups](http://askubuntu.com/questions/569679/whats-a-good-back-up-strategy-for-1-desktop-pc)  You're definitely user type 4 with a software RAID.  *Free tip: on this kind of hardware:* take Lubuntu! :-)